# Neo4j -- how to store graph data in different disks?

Tags: neo4j

I can not find any on Neo4j storage using diferent disks . But ,in fact, there is a large(very large) graph and can not store is in one machine or disk , how to store it using Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use symlinks to do this, and point out different files? Have not tried it, but it should work.

Comment: maybe a good idear! but I do not know whether it will affect the efficiency

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the community version or the enterprise one?  The community version can only be run (as per the license) on a single node - you can run it in embedded fashion or on a separate machine and access it from your service (Java/REST APIs).  The enterprise version can be run on multiple nodes as per their license.

Comment: What you say is HA mode？ actually ,different machines  have same copy

Comment: I thought you wanted to store the data onto two different computers somehow (and not just copy data from one box to another) - I believe you mentioned you have a very large graph which cannot be stored on one machine/disk.  good luck with your project

Comment: yes,I can not found any about that, So i am going to split the properties of Nodes;Do you have some good idears?